# Does AFNetworking support chunk-encoding download?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

Does AFNetworking support chunk-encoding download? and how to use it?
Some examples would be very appreciated?

Comment: Hi, I have the same question, have you found out if it's supported by AfNetworking or you had to implement your own using NSURLConnection? Thanks

Comment: No, I had to implement my own directly use NSURLConnection.